# How to access a child of a ControlTemplate applied to a ContentView of a ContentPage, from the ContentPage?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui, controltemplate

So I'm trying to design a page which can have two different appearances depending on a state defined at runtime.
I don't have much experience with MAUI or XAML in general but I am trying to do it the right way, and so here is what I did:

- I defined two ControlTemplate elements in the ContentPage's resources.
- I defined the common UI in ContentPage's content, and defined a ContentView element that consumes the content from one of the two ControlTemplate elements, which is set in the xaml.cs code file of the page depending on the state of the ViewModel bound to it.

Here is the simplified XAML code from the page:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                   xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
                   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
                   >
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="template1">
        <Grid RowDefinitions="*,*,*">
            <Label Text="TEMPLATE1 UI..."/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
    
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="template2">
        <Grid RowDefinitions="*,*,*">
            <Label Text="TEMPLATE2 UI..."/>
            
            <!-- I need to access this element from MainPage.xaml.cs -->
            <local:MyCustomControl x:Name="myCustomControl"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ContentPage.Resources>


<Grid RowDefinitions="*, *, *">
    <!-- Here goes my common UI -->
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="COMMON UI..."/>
    
    <!-- Here goes one of my two ControlTemplate UI -->
    <ContentView x:Name="contentFromTemplate" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
</Grid>
```

Now as you can see, in "template2" ControlTemplate, there is a MyCustomControl element. I am trying to access this element from the cs code of the page but without any success. I understand that if the ControlTemplate was to be applied to the page, I could access it with the GetTemplateChild method, but that does not work in my case since the ControlTemplate is applied to a ContentView, in the page.

**-> How can I access the "myCustomControl" element from MainPage.xaml.cs ?**

I am unsure my approach is the correct one though, and I appreciate any input on a better one, thanks a lot for taking the time to read.

Comment: why do you need to do this?

Comment: To make them visible/invisible? No. Two separate pages. In the constructors - the same ViewModel with the logic. And interface you can shape to your heart desire. Navigation to one of them depending on your "runtime variable".

Comment: I am trying to avoid duplicating UI code as much as possible, and my two UI have a lot in common, simply some elements will go to a different position on the page depending on my ViewModel's state. I initially had two different pages as you recommand @H.A.H I think I will go back to this approach as it seems I might have got lost in the wood with all this...

Comment: @Toto It is not about getting lost in the wood. It is about what is right and what is wrong. You want two different UI, so you make two pages. That is it. You don't want to repeat UI code? Good. Make templates. But templates for the part that stays the same, not the part that changes. Use template binding, for everything in the template. No direct access to controls inside it. No matter the reason.

Comment: Maybe show a mockup of what you want to achieve, then someone may be able to provide a general approach for this. From your description, it's not entirely clear what your actual goal is and your approach seems unnecessarily complicated. Avoiding code duplication at all cost is not advisable either, that can quickly lead to incorrect abstractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to avoid duplicating UI code as much as possible, and my
> two UI have a lot in common, simply some elements will go to a
> different position on the page depending on my ViewModel's state.

As a summary, I will post an answer.

For this problem, there are several ways to achieve this.

1.Since there are a lot in common for the two UT, one common method is to show and hide some elements based on your view model.

For example, you can set property `IsVisible` for your views:

```
 if(Your conditional statement is true)
      yourview.IsVisible = true;
  else
      yourview.IsVisible = false;
```

2.another way is to use two separate pages depending on the ViewModel's state, just as H.A.H mentioned.